# ¿Como usar ng-click de esta forma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

Probablemente este mal hacerlo de esta forma, pero solo asi encontre darle funcionalidad a datatable.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $("#example-1").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                "url": "http://162.100.100.100/proyecto/public/ws/usuarios",
                "dataSrc": "records"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "nombre1" },
                    { "data": "apellido1" },
                    { "data": "usuario" },
                    { "data": "idtipousuario" },
                    { "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-icon btn-info' ng-click='openModal(dataUsuario,'modal-2', 'lg');'><i class='fa-edit'></i></button>" }   
                ]
            });

             $('#example-1').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
                        //var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                       console.log("Mostrar Modal")
               });
        });
    </script>
```

Por cada registro que lleno en la tabla, le agrego un boton

```
"defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-icon btn-info' ng-click='openModal(dataUsuario,'modal-2', 'lg');'><i class='fa-edit'></i></button>"
```

Como puedo hacer con este boton mediante ng-click mostrar un modal?. Anteriormente llenaba la tabla con ng-repeat, pero perdia la pagina, busqueda del datatable.

Como podria hacer esto, o de que otra forma puedo hacerlo y si no es posible muchas gracias. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una excelente forma de implementar lo que necesitas es usando [SmartTable](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

Espero te ayude amigo!

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado, pero tengo problemas al implimentar la busqueda global de SmartTable, no realiza la busqueda. Este es mi caso: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54782/angularjs-busqueda-global-de-smart-table-no-funciona-con-esta-data por si puede ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

creo que usar angular de la forma que lo estás haciendo no te va a funcionar. Lo mejor sería que cambiases el código html que estás generando para usar el evento onclick en lugar de ng-click.