# AngularJS: Busqueda global de Smart Table no funciona con esta data

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente problema que aplico Smart Table de angular. Los registros los obtengo de esta manera

```
$http.get('../ws/usuarios').success(function(datas)
    {
        $scope.rowCollection = datas.records;
        console.log($scope.rowCollection);
    });
```

y Aqui mi tabla, muestra bien todos los registros, pero al hacer uso de la busqueda global, no funciona. lo hago tal y como esta en la documentacion. No se cual sera mi error.

Tabla:

```
<div class="panel-body">            
    <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th st-sort="id">#</th>
                <th st-sort="nombre1">Nombre</th>
                <th st-sort="apellido1">Apellido</th>
                <th st-sort="usuario">Usuario</th>
                <th>Tipo de usuario</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6"><input st-search placeholder="Busqueda" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{row.nombre1}}</td>
                <td>{{row.apellido1}}</td>
                <td>{{row.usuario}}</td>
                <td>{{row.idtipousuario}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-icon btn-info" ng-click="openModal(row,'modal-2', 'lg');"><i class="fa-edit"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-icon btn-red" ng-click="openModal(row,'modal-3', 'lg');"><i class="fa-remove"></i></button>  
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Aca el cuadro de texto para realizar busqueda

```
<th colspan="6"><input st-search placeholder="Busqueda" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/></th>
```

segun la documentacion con la propiedad `st-search` ya aplicaria realizar la busqueda, pero nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, para que te funcione la búsqueda global (según la documentación de SmartTable) es que debes añadir st-safe-src a la etiqueta table

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="collection" class="table table-striped">...</table>
```

Si revisas la línea que he puesto, te percatarás que *st-table* esta referenciando a *displayedCollection*, la cual es una "copia" de tu fuente base (en este caso *rowCollection*); imagino que hacen esto para mantener intacto tu fuente de datos original.

Por lo que resumiendo, **st-table** es la colección donde se hará la búsqueda y **st-safe-src** es tu colección original.

Acá un ejemplo en [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDuIa2JshGgZnRmn2BcG?p=preview)

Comment: Excelente muchisimas gracias, ya me funciono. Lo que no comprendia es que cuando utilizaba el arreglo que viene por default en la documentacion "rowCollection", con ese si me aplicaba la busqueda.